# Missing URI template variable 'pagesize' for method parameter of type int

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am developping an angular-springboot application and I cannot reach a springboot controller.
Here is my controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api"})
public class ProduitImmobilierController {

    @Autowired
    private ProduitImmobilierServiceImpl userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/produitimmobilier/all/{{pagesize}}/{{page}}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
    consumes = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody List<ProduitImmobilierDTO> findAll(@PathVariable("pagesize") int pagesize, @PathVariable("page") int page){
        return userService.findAll(pagesize, page);
    }
```

Here is my angular service

```
  getListProduitImmobilierDTO(pagesize: number, page: number): Observable<ProduitImmobilierDTO[]> {
    const headerDict = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Accept-Charset': 'charset=UTF-8',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
    };

    const requestOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(headerDict)
    };
    return this.http.get('/api/produitimmobilier/all/' + pagesize + '/' + page, requestOptions).pipe(map((jsonArray: any) =>jsonArray.map((jsonItem) => ProduitImmobilierDTO.fromJson(jsonItem))));
  }
```

I have the following error message in my firefox console

```
error: "Internal Server Error"
​​
message: "Missing URI template variable 'pagesize' for method parameter of type int"
​​
path: "/api/produitimmobilier/all/5/1"
​​
status: 500
```

The request doen't even reach the springboot controller. Can you help me ?

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I didn't see that I put double brackets instead of simple' s one. {{pagesize}}/{{page}} -> {pagesize}/{page}. It is resolved. Thank you

Comment: Add your comment as an answer as it is the answer to the problem you have. You will be able to accept it as an answer later so the question no longer an 'unanswered' one.